# BroadcastReceiver generates two notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to use the BroadcastReceiver to receive a push notification containing only text, and it seems that it's simultaneously generating two notifications: one that is only the text I'm pushing, and one that includes all of the formatting and styles I've included in my NotificationCompat.Builder object. I know it's something inherent in how BroadcastReceiver is coded, because I've commented out the entire body of my onReceive() method and it still generates that basic notification. Is there a way to suppress that basic notification so it only sends the notification that I'm manually building?

Here's my code:

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

        Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
        Iterator itr = json.keys();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) itr.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));

            if (key.equals("alert"))
            {
                //Save the message to the globalDataString
                SplashActivity.globalDataString.push(json.getString(key).toString());
                SplashActivity.notificationFlag = true;

                //call the method that generates and sends the notification I want
                receiveNotification();

                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:* Here is the code for my receiveNotification() class:

```
public void receiveNotification() {


NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bts = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
bts.bigText(SplashActivity.globalDataString);
bts.setSummaryText("Tap to open app, swipe to dismiss message");

NotificationCompat.Builder m = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
m.setContentTitle("New Push Notification")
    .setContentText(SplashActivity.globalDataString)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
    .setStyle(bts);

Intent openApp = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);

// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// the application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MenuActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(openApp);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
m.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

Notification noti = m.build();

NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(pushMessageID, noti);
pushMessageID++;

//reset notification
flag1 = false;
```

}

Comment: Please include your `generateNotification()` code.

Comment: Apologies, that should be **receiveNotification(). It's the same code from the last question you helped answer :)

Comment: I'd check two things : 1. Make sure that your server doesn't send the same notification twice to the same device (it could happen, for example, if your DB contains multiple registration IDs for the same device). 2. Try passing the context parameter of `onReceive` to receiveNotification(), and use it instead of `this` (I'm not sure if that would make any difference, but that's what I do).